# AngularJS http POST with $scope

Tags: ajax, angularjs, http, angularjs-scope

I am trying to do a http post using AngularJS but angular is not converting my `$scope` variable to JSON.

Here is my code:

```
        $http({
                method: "POST",
                url: "/Account/Login",
                data: $scope
            })
```

Which results in the request POST message having

```
"$SCOPE"
```

but if I change it to output any of my scope properties, it is sending the message with correct properties, e.g.:

```
        $http({
                method: "POST",
                url: "/Account/Login",
                data: { email: $scope.email, password: $scope.password }
            })
```

Which results in the request POST message having

```
{"email":"asdasd@Asdasd.asd","password":"asd"}
```

Do I always have to wrap my requests like this? Or is there a way to tell AngularJS to send all properties on scope? Any Pro's / Con's?

Comment: don't use `$scope`. Use an inner object like `$scope.data` which has `data.email` and `data.password`. It does say to do this in the manual because `ngIf` and `ngRepeat` will isolate your primitive scope variables.

Answer (score 6):

Sending the $scope is not a good idea, It contains lot more than your `email` and `password`

You should create a property like `$scope.user` and then attach the model to it like `$scope.user.email`. Now you can send it using `$scope.user`

```
$http({
     method: "POST",
     url: "/Account/Login",
     data: $scope.user
})
```

a lil about `$scope`

> scope is an "object" that "binds" to DOM element where you apply controller. All child elements can read and modify scope data (unless you modify primitives in new scopes or they're isolated

[for more official doc is they way](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/scope)

Comment: I was doing that earlier, (having a formData object inside scope) but then that means everything in my form needs to bind to formData.email, etc.

Comment: Is tehre anyway to change $scope or the root of t he bindings of inner objects inside a form? E.g. bindg form to $scope.user, and then on inputs have only ng-model="email" which would be bound to $scope.user.email?